# how to use golang's zlib?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

```
var buf bytes.Buffer

var outputBuffer [100]byte
b := []byte(`{"Name":"Wednesday","Age":6,"Parents":["Gomez","Morticia"],"test":{"prop1":1,"prop2":[1,2,3]}}`)

w := zlib.NewWriter(&buf)
r, _ := zlib.NewReader(&buf)
w.Write(b)
w.Flush()
r.Read(outputBuffer)//cannot use outputBuffer (type [100]byte) as type []byte in function argument
fmt.Println(outputBuffer)
```

what can I do to make this right? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well you tried to use an array as a slice.  It expected a `[]byte` and you gave it a `[100]byte`.  A `[]byte` has a dynamic width, while a `[100]byte` is always 100 bytes.  An array's size is a part of its type; a `[1]int` is a different type from a `[2]int`.  That's why almost everything operates on slices.

But that's not the only thing.  When you call `Read` on an `io.Reader` directly, it fills in the target slice up to its current width, without expanding it.  If you had made your output slice 10 bytes wide (`make([]byte, 10)`), the output you would see would be `{"Name":"W`.

```
var in bytes.Buffer
b := []byte(`{"Name":"Wednesday","Age":6,"Parents":["Gomez","Morticia"],"test":{"prop1":1,"prop2":[1,2,3]}}`)
w := zlib.NewWriter(&in)
w.Write(b)
w.Close()

var out bytes.Buffer
r, _ := zlib.NewReader(&in)
io.Copy(&out, r)
os.Stdout.Write(out.Bytes())
```

but at this point, you might as well just pass `os.Stdout` into `io.Copy`, just like they do in [the standard library docs](http://golang.org/pkg/compress/zlib/).  The only difference is we have kept a copy of the output format, but... what if the output is so large that you don't want to hold it in memory?  That's why `io.Copy` takes an interface: you can take compressed data, and write an uncompressed version of it directly to any output stream, including stdout but also including things like files, unix sockets, or network sockets.

Answer (score -3):

Try one of the following:

```
r.Read([]byte(outputBuffer))
```

or

```
r.Read(outputBuffer[0:100])
```

I believe it has to do with Go's concept of slices versus fixed size arrays. You can read more about these concepts here (the sections about Arrays and Slices):

http://www.golang-book.com/6

There are other ways as well, for instance making your outputBuffer a proper slice initially instead of a fixed length array, but with the pointer above you should be able to figure it out.